# Stream esp-32 camera to RMTP server like YouTube

Tags: esp32, camera, espressif, stream

I am doing research for a project in which I need to play with camera streams. After multiple hit and trails and googling I am not getting even close to the **solution for streaming ESP-32 Camera stream to my own RMTP server directly**.

Already tried solutions:

1) I have tried re-streaming of ESP-32-cam with Raspberry pi, that works well but not something I am looking for

2) ESP-32-cam: Record and FTP transfer with time triggers (Not tried but believed that it is not a good approach).

Please note: I am not looking at the solution in which ESP-32 cam acts as stream server and browser can connect to it like : https://www.hackster.io/BnBe_Club/9-rtsp-video-streamer-using-the-esp32-cam-board-8832b4

I have already tried it and it works well but not for the usecase which involves streaming to RTMP server without restreaming.

On google, I found a similar thread : https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=634605.0
The guy with solution is not interested in sharing it.

may be some modification required in below code **MAY BE**
ref: https://github.com/espressif/esp32-camera

```
static esp_err_t stream_handler(httpd_req_t *req){
  camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
  esp_err_t res = ESP_OK;
  size_t _jpg_buf_len = 0;
  uint8_t * _jpg_buf = NULL;
  char * part_buf[64];

  res = httpd_resp_set_type(req, _STREAM_CONTENT_TYPE);
  if(res != ESP_OK){
    return res;
  }

  while(true){
    fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
    if (!fb) {
      Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
      res = ESP_FAIL;
    } else {
      if(fb->width > 400){
        if(fb->format != PIXFORMAT_JPEG){
          bool jpeg_converted = frame2jpg(fb, 80, &_jpg_buf, &_jpg_buf_len);
          esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
          fb = NULL;
          if(!jpeg_converted){
            Serial.println("JPEG compression failed");
            res = ESP_FAIL;
          }
        } else {
          _jpg_buf_len = fb->len;
          _jpg_buf = fb->buf;
        }
      }
    }
    if(res == ESP_OK){
      size_t hlen = snprintf((char *)part_buf, 64, _STREAM_PART, _jpg_buf_len);
      res = httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, (const char *)part_buf, hlen);
    }
    if(res == ESP_OK){
      res = httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, (const char *)_jpg_buf, _jpg_buf_len);
    }
    if(res == ESP_OK){
      res = httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, _STREAM_BOUNDARY, strlen(_STREAM_BOUNDARY));
    }
    if(fb){
      esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
      fb = NULL;
      _jpg_buf = NULL;
    } else if(_jpg_buf){
      free(_jpg_buf);
      _jpg_buf = NULL;
    }
    if(res != ESP_OK){
      break;
    }
    //Serial.printf("MJPG: %uB\n",(uint32_t)(_jpg_buf_len));
  }
  return res;
}
```